# Angularjs - Calling json web service always returns 404

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to angularjs. I am using it with ionic framework. I am trying to calling a json web service but it always returns 404.

When I try in browser it works perfectly fine.

here is my code:

```
function FetchCtrl($scope, $http) {

    $scope.fetch = function() {

        $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://example.com/anyservice'}).
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            alert("data "+data);
          }).
          error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            alert("error "+status);

          });

      };
 }
```

Comment: Try the get request on http://example.com/anyservice with a browser http request to see if the service really responds

Comment: Is the API on a different domain than the angular app is loaded from? In that case it could be a CORS problem.

Comment: I checked in Rest Console, the service is responding properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either Chrome or FireFox Developer Tools and open the Network tab, then give it a shot and see what the actual request is that is happening, that should help you finding your problem.

Comment: Hey I checked it again on Chrome Developer Tool and came to point that my server was not allowing access of the service from other server. so I created a service and placed it to my server. Now I am getting the response properly. Thanks for you help.